# Check if a user is logged in or not on product page using OpenCart 2.3.X

Tags: opencart

I'm using Opencart 2.3.0.2 and would liek to show or hide the product code based on if the user is logged in.

in product.tpl I have tried changing:

```
 <li><?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $model; ?></li>
```

to

```
  <?php if ($logged) { ?>       
  <li><?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $model; ?></li>
  <?php } ?>
```

but I get an error message stating that logged is not defined in product.tpl

I have also editing controller/common/header.php to include the following in various places with no luck.

```
$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to get a User or a Customer? If the customer then answer from KB looks Ok, if User then you can check like below https://webocreation.com/blog/check-admin-logged-front-page-opencart-2-3/

Answer (score 1):

You must declare logged in corresponding controller file. So you nee add `$data['logged'] = $this->customer->isLogged();`
to:
`catalog/controller/product/product.php` file.